# Trigger tweenmax animation when element in viewport and reset when not in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am trying to make background images to zoom-out once the section is in the viewport and when section leaves the viewport the background image should get set to its initial state(that is, zoomed in). I have made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev93/k07Lxfad/3/).

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// loop through all elements
$('.zoom').each(function() {

  var tween = new TimelineMax();

  var zoomOut = TweenLite.from($(this),3,{scale:2,rotationZ:0.01});
  var zoomIn = TweenLite.to($(this),0.01,{scale:1,rotationZ:0});

tween
    .add(zoomOut)
    .add(zoomIn)

  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: this, offset: '50%'})
  .setTween(tween) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
  .addIndicators()
  .addTo(controller);

});
```

In this, the image in the First Section only animates once and the animation is not working as intended when I scroll back suppose from section 3 to section 2. I am trying to make something like on this [website](https://75kenmare.com/residences/).

Please help.

Comment: This is very straightforward using the Intersection Observer API. No need for ScrollMagic: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21444-text-animation/?tab=comments#comment-101205